# Where are VC++ 2010 basic include files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include-path

Where does Visual Studio 2010 store the core header files for the C language?  stdio.h and stuff like that? Please do not answer me along the lines of "It's where the 'Include directories' item in the property sheet says it is" because that just says "$(VCInstallDir)include" and I have been trying for an hour without success to trace $(VCInstallDir).

1. Can someone please tell me the EXACT PATH where a default install of VS2010 would put these include files?
2. Can someone tell me how to get VS to spit out the actual content of macros like $(VCInstallDir)?

Comment: For Win 7 it's here: Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include. Note that some include files like windows.h are stored "internally" and don't exist in the include directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I'm going to answer both questions, even though rcgldr already answered the first as a comment.

1) Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include

2) Open a developer command prompt (there is a shortcut in the start menu folder for Visual Studio) and type `echo %VCInstallDir%` or `set` will show you all of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, Phil. Yes, I was completely thrown by the fact that it installs in Program Files (x86) not Program Files. But understanding how to dump the variables will be a big help for the future.